# Ошибка при попытке установить зависимости с помощью Composer

Tags: yii, composer

У меня есть проект на Yii, для которого я пытаюсь установить зависимости с помощью команды

```
composer install
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1                             
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-composer 2.0.3 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-composer[2.0.3].
    - yiisoft/yii2-composer 2.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2                             
    - yiisoft/yii2-composer 2.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires yiisoft/yii2-composer * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-composer[2.0.3].
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.6].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Команду

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2"
```

выполнял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил данную проблему, выполнив вместо команды `composer install` команду `composer update`.